# 3d plot with axes of same length

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some 3D trajectories I want to plot.
Since they vary a lot in XY, but much less in Z, the default plot3 is misleading, because it automatically scales axes.

I've been told to use `axes equal` but it has no effect (see the commented line where I used it).

I came up with this code, which in my opinion is very long to achieve a so simple task:

```
[D,rate]=read_vicon_ascii('csvdata/a1-0.csv');
% or replace above line with D=csvread('stackoverflow-31289872.csv');
% get stackoverflow-31289872.csv at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5GjKiDZk3F5UHlVQUxKeFo4SG8/view?pli=1

% indices of X,Y,Z columns
X = 1+(2:3:14);
Y = 2+(2:3:14);
Z = 3+(2:3:14);

Bounds = [  min(min(D(:,X))) max(max(D(:,X)))
            min(min(D(:,Y))) max(max(D(:,Y)))
            min(min(D(:,Z))) max(max(D(:,Z))) ];
MaxDelta = max(Bounds(:,2)-Bounds(:,1));
SquareBounds = Bounds;
for xyz=1:3
    Delta = SquareBounds(xyz,2) - SquareBounds(xyz,1);
    SquareBounds(xyz,:) = SquareBounds(xyz,:) + (MaxDelta - Delta) * [-0.5 0.5];
end

figure
hold on
for i=1:5
    plot3(D(:,X(i)),D(:,Y(i)),D(:,Z(i)),'r-')
end
xlim(SquareBounds(1,:))
ylim(SquareBounds(2,:))
zlim(SquareBounds(3,:))
%axes equal
hold off
```

Is there any way to make it better. (or a correct usage of `axes equal` if that does what is supoosed to do?)

Comment: You should provide sample data so people can actually run your code. Otherwise we can guess a few improvements but there is no point in suggesting if we cannot be sure it'll be effective.

Comment: @Hoki you can find a csv dump of `D` [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5GjKiDZk3F5UHlVQUxKeFo4SG8/view?pli=1)

Comment: `axes equal`: Use the same length for the data units along each axis.

Comment: If you just comment out all your `nlims` and uncomment `axis equal` it works like a charm. Whats your question?

Comment: for some reason "axes equal" does not produce an error but this is a typo. The correct syntax is **`axis equal`**

Comment: @AnderBiguri doh I didn't notice the error after my typo. It worked.